# Grails 2.2.3 - lots of resources in project root makes the app hang forever

Tags: grails

I have this Grails 2.2.3 (still...) application. It's a normal app using GORM, and SpringSecurity, nothing unusual.
The only unusual thing is when the app goes in production, the webapps/ROOT folder (where the app lives) is populated by a lot of other folders in the root of it. These folders do not contain stuff that is needed by Grails, but for reasons I find shameful ^_^; , they have to be there. I'm talking about a huge amount of directories with various depths.

The big problem here is at Tomcat restart, the whole process hangs with a beautiful:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

and takes like 40 minutes to proceed further.

Using JVisual, we noticed the reason was a huge amount of directory listing and file reads.
We never reproduced this behavior locally, until we noticed this thing. We recreated an environment full of directories and violà, same behavior.

Now:

1. anyone can confirm my guess is right
2. any idea on how I can "disable" this search on uninteresting paths (or tell which are interesting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can confirm this is actually happening. When Grails starts, it looks into its webapp directory and scans looking for something. If the directory is stuck with content, it'll hang forever.
We didn't find a solution to this problem but found a way to move those resources away from the folder.
So keep in mind: always keep your webapp directory clean form stuff that can be moved elsewhere.